# jquery-1.6.4.min.js automatically redirect to google home page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have downloaded  a website using HTtrack wepsite copier. All files are downloaded to my local system . But if i run the file in my local system it automatically redirect to the come page. This action is done by using the http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_37010/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js . I tried to remove that automatic redirection script but no use.please help me how to remove that script.

Comment: Please click a link in my post you'll get the full js code

Comment: You have downloaded a website? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of the file is an obfuscated version of:

```
if(!location.protocol.indexOf('http:') && !location.host.indexOf('template-help.com')) {
    // nothing
} else {
    location.href='http://www.google.com';
}
```

Note that downloading this template and using it on your own site is a violation of Template-Help's copyright. If you want to use the template, ***PAY FOR IT***.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using 1.6.4 consider using

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

It will eliminate your problem :)

After you have played with template, please consider contributing $60 or so to developer. In other words: BUY it! You will have benefits of having all files support and PSD files as well for lousy $60.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `jquery-1.6.min.js` file with `jquery.min.js` in index.html as well.